# Is it correct that using two mediumtext fields in a MySQL table will only add 22 bytes to row size?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a table with a `TEXT` column and a `MEDIUMTEXT` column (in addition to other columns). I know the maximum size of a row for MySQL 5+ is [65,535 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

Am I reading it correctly that due to their data being stored separately from the table/row, that `BLOB`/`TEXT` columns only add 9 to 12 bytes to a row's length?

> BLOB and TEXT columns count from one to four plus eight bytes each toward the row-size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the row.

So, the following table would only count against the maximum row size **282 bytes**?

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    summary TEXT NOT NULL,
    description MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Without doing the arithmetic, your estimate seems reasonable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I wanted to be sure I wasn't going to get rejected rows for size reasons

Comment: . . . A simple reality check is that the MEDIUMTEXT and TEXT (and BLOB) data types would be useless, if they were limited to 64k.